# Lua not recognizing existent methods?

Tags: lua, fivem

In my framework project that I'm creating, I have the following issue:

I have a `Player` class with various methods, one of them being `GetIdentifier()`.

I exported the `ZMan` namespace to be able to use it in other resources (as the game calls them), I am able to use every method within the `ZMan` namespace, without an issue.

But when I go to get the player instance, and then use a player method I get weird behaviour.
Relevant code:

```lua
    -- Another resource, including the ZMan export
    Citizen.CreateThread(function()
      Wait(1500) -- Wait for the table to be filled
    
      for k, v in pairs(ZMan.GetPlayers()) do
        local Player = ZMan.Get(k) -- Get the player instance
        print(Player:GetIdentifier()) -- Prints the identifier, works fine.
      end
    end)
    
    -- Base resource (framework)

    ZMan.Get = function(src)
      if ZMan.Players[src] ~= nil then
        return ZMan.Players[src] -- Returns the class instance of this player
      end
    
      Utils.Logger.Debug(("Cannot get ~green~%s's~white~ object! Doesn't exist on ~lblue~Players~white~ table!"):format(src))
    end
```

Player class: https://github.com/iWanheda/zm-core/blob/main/framework/server/classes/player.lua

The whole code for this can be found @ https://github.com/iWanheda/zm-core/

That first code works fine on the base resource (framework), but doesn't work on other resources, which is weird since everything else works except for Player class's methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aaaaa, never able to make a proper thread with this formatting system, helpppp :')

Comment: I forgot to include that, it says it's undefined.

Comment: What do you mean what's undefined? "But when I go to get the player instance, and then use a player method I get weird behaviour." which "weird behaviour" stands for undefined, methods are undefined.

Comment: you said "it is undefined", so I asked what you mean by that. because it isn't clear. as is your whole post. take a deep breach and reword it. there is no point in providing the actual meaning of your sentences in comments. edit your actual post so it makes sense. if you say those methods are undefined there should be some function call and some error message about calling nil values or similar. provide that error. and again, read [ask] befor you continue.

Comment: you are calling `ZMan.Get` before it is defined, move the definition to before `Citizen.CreateThread`

Comment: No I am not, read the comments above both `.CreateThread()` and `ZMan.Get` one is in the main resource, the other is in other resource, which is started AFTER the base resource is started (framework)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was calling the methods with `:` instead of `.`, it's fixed now.